# VBA: Retrieve cell value from each row in Range.Area

Tags: vba, excel

The main goal is: Retrieve specific cell values from each row in a filtered table by using column reference name.

So far, I have the following code

```
Dim table As listObject
Dim columns As ListColumns
Dim row As ListRow
Dim rnData As range
Dim rngArea As range

Set table = Sheets(sheetName).ListObjects(TableName)
Set columns = table.ListColumns
Set rnData = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(sheetName).ListObjects(TableName).range 
'Notice that sheetName and TableName are function arguments. No need to pay attention. Consider any string values.

'Filter my table
table.range.AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:=Array("filtervalue1", "filtervalue2"), Operator:=xlFilterValues

'Set the filtered table in a new Range object
Set rnData = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(sheetName).ListObjects(TableName).range

'Count all rows of my filtered table
With rnData
    For Each rngArea In .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Areas
        lCount = lCount + rngArea.Rows.Count
    Next
End with
```

Now I want to loop my filtered table (my "rnData" range) and I want to get the cell value for each row in those Range.Areas.

I was thinking something like this, but i'm having difficulties with VBA to do this:

```
For iRowNo = 2 To (lCount - 1) 'Start at 2 because 1 is the table header
            'This does not work once it gets another row from the entire table. Not the filtered one. Help here!
            Set row = table.ListRows(iRowNo)

            'Something close to this - Help Here!
            Set row = rnData.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Areas 

            ''Would like to have the code like this to get the values
            cell1Value= row.range(1, columns("My Column Header 1").Index).value 
            cell2Value= row.range(1, columns("My Column Header 2").Index).Value

Next iRowNo
```

Let me know if there are different solutions than this.

Comment: Why not inside the `For Each rngArea...` loop run another `For Each [variable] in rngArea.rows` loop? This way you will get all the rows (just keep in mind that you are referring a whole row in that limits so you need `[variable].cells(1, y)` if you want to get to a single cell)

Comment: Instructions unclear (sorry for my bad english), can you add pictures of what you have and what you want? It will be easier to others as well, I suppose.

Comment: @DirkReichel thank you for bring that up! That solves the issue. I will answer my own question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following the @DirkReichel answer

Here is the code that worked for me:

```
Dim table As listObject
Dim columns As ListColumns
Dim row As ListRow
Dim rnData As range
Dim rngArea As range

Set table = Sheets(sheetName).ListObjects(TableName)
Set columns = table.ListColumns
Set rnData = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(sheetName).ListObjects(TableName).range 
'Notice that sheetName and TableName are function arguments. No need to pay attention. Consider any string values.

'Filter my table
table.range.AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:=Array("filtervalue1", "filtervalue2"), Operator:=xlFilterValues

'Set the filtered table in a new Range object
Set rnData = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(sheetName).ListObjects(TableName).range

'Get values for each row
With rnData
    For Each rngArea In .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Areas
        For Each row In rngArea.Rows
           cell1Value= row.range(1, columns("My Column Header 1").Index).value 
            cell2Value= row.range(1, columns("My Column Header 2").Index).Value
        Next

       'lCount = lCount + rngArea.Rows.Count 'Removed this.
    Next
End with

'Also no need the second part of code with the For..Next loop.
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you're indirectly trying to create an array which is not something that can be easily explained a single post, but here's some code to get you started.

I'm going to assume that your set `rnData` range is correct. From there, it's probably easiest to just loop through all cells in range. You could write code more precise than below, but this should help you see a couple ideas besides what you're trying.

Most important I think you're looking for a method to create an array. I hope this helps.

```
Sub testCoutinho()
Dim Rcell As Range
Dim rnData As Range 'you'll have to set this up...

Dim YesLetsDoAnArray As Boolean: YesLetsDoAnArray = False 'or change to false to just make a new sheet with values

If YesLetsDoAnArray Then
    ReDim This_is_your_Array(0) As Variant 'Create Array
    Dim x As Integer
Else
    'putting values on a new worksheet in file
    Dim CleanWS As Worksheet: Set CleanWS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add
End If


For Each Rcell In rnData.Cells

    If Rcell.EntireRow.Hidden = False Then

        If YesLetsDoAnArray Then
            ReDim Preserve This_is_your_Array(x)
            This_is_your_Array(x) = Rcell.Value
            x = x + 1
        Else
            CleanWS.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = Rcell.Value
        End If
    End If
Next Rcell


'If you used an array, you'll know have variable(s) that contain all your data.
'your first one is This This_Is_Your_Array(0), followed by This_Is_Your_Array(1)... etc.
'you can play around. this will print them all.

If YesLetsDoAnArray Then
Dim i As Integer

For i = 0 To x - 1
Debug.Print This_is_your_Array(i)
Next i
End If


End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, This could be an option but I wanted to keep similar with my code and use the listobject datatype.